# Fancybox pops up - bottom half of background page disappears

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have set up a test page here: http://www.hestiacookware.com/shop/product.php?s=presentation-product

When you click on any of the images to start Fancybox, half of the background page disappears - it just cuts off at a certain point.

Thank you for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Your layout behaves oddly because these two CSS properties in your [stylesheet.css](http://www.hestiacookware.com/css/stylesheet.css) file :

Line 2 :

```
html {
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Line 5 :

```
body {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #143721;
  width: 100%;
}
```

...unless you have a good reason to have them, I would advice you to remove the `overflow-y:scroll` from the `html` tag AND `width: 100%` from the `body` tag.

Your layout will work just fine without them and will be consistent through most browsers.